# General possibility personal experience can/could/may/might

Tags: semi-modals

Would a native BrE speaker use "may/might/could/can" when talking about both personal experience and general possibility in these examples?

1. "Earthquakes can/could/may/might be frequent/dangerous. (Generally)
2. "Earthquakes can/could/might (not "may") be frequent/dangerous here."
   According to "English Grammar in Context" by Michael Vince "can" is the only option when talking about a general possibility as in sentence 1. I have read that "may" is not used when talking about what is possible based on personal experience as in the second sentence.
3. "Winters can be cold." Generally. Thus either "can", "could",  "may", or "might" is correct here, but
4. "Winters can be cold here" "can", "might", "could" is correct but "may" is not.

Comment: I don't see what difference personal experience makes. It doesn't affect the grammar if we have lived through the cold winters or just read about the climate in a book. I would use _can_ or _may_ for generalisations, but would only use _could_ or _might_ for a hypothetical statement. "Winters in the West of England could become colder if we lost the effect of the Gulf Stream."

Comment: I don't think it makes a blind bit of difference whether you tack ***here*** onto the end of some "generic" assertion like ***Winter can be cold***. Apart from the fact that if such an assertion *isn't* either explicitly or contextually constrained to some particular region, it's a totally pointless thing to say in the first place.

Comment: So its not that either is correct in them. Right? For generalisations only  *can* or *may* not  *could* or *might*.  For hypothetical statements only *could* or *might* . But for experience can I use all if them? If I am talking about the weather in my country and say "Winters can/may/might/could be cold here" would either be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Antonia's country winters can be cold

So I am fairly confident about this

> In Antonia's country winters may be cold

I am slightly less sure, perhaps sometimes they are not

> In Antonia's country winters could become cold

At the moment they are not but with changes in ocean currents they might become colder. You could replace *could* with *might* in that example.

Comment: Thank you, mdewey. Is this understood as a general possibility the book is talking about or is it specific/ based on experience?

Comment: As far as I know it is a general rule.